# Wagtail - как в базе данных сохранить содержимое поля RichText в StreamField кириллицей а не в Unicode?

Tags: unicode, кириллица

Сейчас сохраняется так.

```
[{"type": "container", "value": {"onecol": [{"type": "paragraph", "value": "<h2>\u0413\u043e\u0441\u0443\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0435\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0422\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c\u044f\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u0433\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0435\u044f</h2>", "id": "571557d0-4996-405a-a13c-92991eb21795"}, {"type": "yt_video", "value": [{"type": "add_video", "value": "<div class=\"yt_video\" area-id='iUdCazc2qEs' area-title='\u0413\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0435\u044f' area-height='320'></div>\r\n<div class=\"yt_video\" area-id='M7lc1UVf-VE' area-title='YouTube' area-height='320'></div>", "id": "f08af7b1-3eeb-4620-b0da-c34dde22e462"}], "id": "34c61f07-1eb9-401a-8874-633309d9b62c"}], "twocol": {"left_column": [], "right_column": []}}, "id": "bd446ef5-9cf6-4081-885a-e3cd82d0fdd2"}]
```

А я хочу добиться, чтобы кириллица сохранялась без кодирования.